# Sonar not analyzing Checkstyle, Findbugs, PMD

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I've just updated my local Sonar installation to 3.7 from 3.3. Previously, I've analyzed projects with Sonar using the Maven plugin (clean install sonar:sonar). On this old setup, everything works like a charm, more specifically Checkstyle, Findbugs, PMD violations were added to the Sonar analysis.

Since the upgrade, I'm not getting any Checkstyle, Findbugs, PMD results (violations count == 0, which I cannot imagine to be true as a local Eclipse PMD run results in quite some violations to solve).

During upgrade of Sonar 3.7, I had to remove the Checkstyle, PMD, findbugs plugins on Sonar, as they were included in the Java ecosystem (according to the docs).

Am I missing something, or can you give me any pointers to enable analysis?

Cheers,

Jeroen

Answer (score 1):

You must be missing some jars from the Java Ecosystem. The zip file can be found on http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Ecosystem